# flutter apk crashes while debug app works

Tags: android, flutter, dart, youtube

I build an app which has list of exercises and a link to youtube video. The app works as expected in the debug version but the apk that I built always crashes whenever I click on the button containing the Video link.
I am Using `flutter_youtube` widget.
Since The Debug mode is working as expected What could cause the APK to crash. 
I built the apk using `flutter build apk` and not `flutter install` Does that matter? Also I haven't signed it

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_youtube/flutter_youtube.dart';

````
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: exercise.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(keys[index]),
                trailing: RaisedButton(
                  child: const Text('Watch Video'),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  onPressed: () {
                                FlutterYoutube.playYoutubeVideoByUrl(
                                  apiKey:"API KEY",
                                  videoUrl: exercise[index],
                                  autoPlay: true, //default false
                                );
                              },),),
       ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google documentation

> Important: When you prepare to release your app to your users, follow
>   these steps again and create a new OAuth 2.0 client ID for your
>   production app. For production apps, use your own private key to sign
>   the production app's .apk file. For more information, see Signing your
>   applications.

Based on that I have realized that maybe unless I have an Auth 2.0 API key the app will not work as Youtube will not respond to the Debug API that I have been using.